# Decomposition of vector space to produce nilpotent and invertible transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum, nilpotence, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Prove that there exists a unique sum $V=V_{0}+V_{1}$ such $T(V_{0}) \subseteq V_{0}$, $T(V_{1}) \subseteq V_{1}$, $T|_{V_{0}}$ is nilpotent, and $T|_{V_{1}}$ is invertible.

Is this exercise related to invariant spaces and direct sums? I was reading the theory, and I can't see how start the problem.

Comment: @DonThousand In that question the person know that $T$ can see as a direct sum of a nilpotent and an invertible operator so, they didn't explain that part.

Comment: Do we need an additional hypothesis on $T,$ or am I missing something? If $T$ is the zero operator, then it is not possible to find any subspace of $V$ on which $T$ is invertible.

Comment: @Carlo, No, that's all. I think, they didn't considerer that case